# How to eliminate disabled items in combox box in QTP

Tags: qtp

I am new to QTP .
I am doing automation on a Java Application, which has a combo box and in which few items are disabled but when I try to retrieve values from it , it takes all of them including the ones which are disabled.

How cal I eliminate disabled items for JavaList and capture only enabled values
Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

Get the innerhtml of the combobox and split along the  html tag. Check for disabled attribute by using InStr and you can get the values that are disabled.